# Implementing 2way Fixed Effects

Tags: regression, econometrics, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

My objective is to assess the impact on BMI following the establishment of a new donut shop in the neighborhood, particularly considering that the donut shop commenced operations in 2017.

Researchers have proposed two-way fixed effects (TWFE) models of this type to analyze such events:

$y_{i,t}$ = $\beta_0$ + $\beta_1$$Z_i$ + $\beta_2$$t$ + $\beta_3$$Z_{it}$

Here
$y$ is outcome.

$Z_i$ is the post/pre binary indicator variable . $Z=1$ indicates post period , $Z=0$ indicates pre period.

$t$ is the time variable in years , values : 2001, 2002, 2003...so on...

Here $\beta_3$ is the causal parameter of interest.

When I implement this model

```
 ID         BMI    Year     Z   
  1        10.12  2003      0 
  2        19.78  2003      0 
  3        7.12   2004      0 
  3        31.56  2005      0
  4        24.12  2006      1
  5        21.67  2007      0  
  .        .      .         . 
  .        .      .         . 
  .        .      .         .
  .        .      .         .  
  2000     11.12  2002      0 
  2001     29.78  2006      1 
  2002     17.12  2008      0  
  2122     13.56  2009      0  
  2676     42.12  2006      1 
  2676     12.67  2007      0
```

`lm(BMI ~ Year + Z + Year*Z, df)`

I get NAs in my parameter estimates for interaction terms after fitting the model based on this method. Below is the reproduceable example.

```
###### Generate random heights and weights
heights <- rnorm(1000, mean = 170, sd = 10)  # Random heights (mean=170, sd=10)
weights <- rnorm(1000, mean = 70, sd = 5)   # Random weights (mean=70, sd=5)

###### Calculate BMI
bmi <- weights / ((heights / 100) ^ 2) 

years       <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018,  2019,  2020, 2021)
percentages <- c(0.1,  0.71, 0.4,  0.45, 0.58, 0.72, 0.15, 0.8,  2.35, 3.79, 3.82, 4.12, 4.59, 4.10, 5.87, 7.13, 8.67, 9.07, 16.23, 22.19, 2.28, 1.81)

Year <- sample(rep(years, round(length(years) * percentages)), 1000, replace = TRUE)

Z <- ifelse(Year > "2017",1,0)

testdf <- as.data.frame(cbind(bmi, Year,Z))

# fit linear model
lm(bmi ~ as.factor(Year) + as.factor(Z) + as.factor(Year)*as.factor(Z), testdf)
```

I like to learn where I am going wrong. Any suggestions are valued and much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting topic. Are you assessing the individuals frequenting this donut shop over time, or are you looking at the average BMI of the residents living in the neighborhood pre-/post-opening of the donut shop?

Comment: @ThomasBilach, good question. How many times an individual visited the shop will be included in the model as a covariate. The actual dataset contains repeat observations for several subjects during pre-post period but it is very unbalanced. Some participants we have 3 observations during different years, for some participants only one.

Comment: And you’re keeping track of the subjects that do *not* visit the shop, and measuring their BMI over time?

Comment: @ThomasBilach, Hi Tomas this question has been bothering me.  The donut store was opened in 2017. Suppose I have pre 2017 BMI data from kids who never visited the donut store after it opened and post 2017 BMI data from kids who visited the donut store, does that make two way fixed effects completely useless ? because I cannot estimate the interaction term ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year effects are identified because you have people observed at multiple years in the data.

The post effect is identified because you have four separate post years.

The year-post effects are not identified because of perfect collinearity:

```
> table(testdf$Year,testdf$Z)
      
         0   1
  2000   1   0
  2001   4   0
  2002   4   0
  2003   8   0
  2004   7   0
  2005   7   0
  2007   6   0
  2008  28   0
  2009  34   0
  2010  44   0
  2011  39   0
  2012  52   0
  2013  42   0
  2014  50   0
  2015  72   0
  2016  78   0
  2017  99   0
  2018   0 163
  2019   0 214
  2020   0  28
  2021   0  20
```

You will need to have some people who are not exposed to the donut shop in the post years get these coefficients. Z cannot be a function of the year only.